# DRF Custom throttle rate doesn't work, default rate works

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to set up the throttle rate for all users to 100 requests per 15 minutes.

The problem is that when I override `AnonRateThrottle` and `UserRateThrottle`, the throttling doesn't work at all.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
         'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
         'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
     ],
     'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': { # I've lowered the rates to test it
         'anon': '2/min',
         'user': '2/min'
     }

}
```

Works perfectly.

This does not work:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'api.throttle_rates.AnonHundredPerFifteenMinutesThrottle',
        'api.throttle_rates.UserHundredPerFifteenMinutesThrottle',
    ],
}
```

**api.throttle_rates**

```
     from rest_framework.throttling import AnonRateThrottle, UserRateThrottle

    class AnonHundredPerFifteenMinutesThrottle(AnonRateThrottle):
        def parse_rate(self, rate):
            return (2, 60)
    
    
    class UserHundredPerFifteenMinutesThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
        def parse_rate(self, rate):
            return (2,60)
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look into [allow_request](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L116) function

`self.rate` is always `None` as you did not set it,
hence request is allowed